# How to upload multiple images using single multipart request in retrofit 2 beta 4?

Tags: android, multipart, retrofit2

I am using `Retrofit 2.0.0-beta 4`. I am trying to upload multiple images using a single `multipart request`:

The API Service method looks like:

```
 @Multipart
@POST("/feedback/add")
Call<ApiResponse> sendFeedbackWithImage(
        @Part("token") RequestBody token,
        @Part("subject") RequestBody subject,
        @Part("message") RequestBody message,
        @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> images);
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not getting error on client side and the logs for the request are like:

```
 02-24 16:25:57.961 9918-14402/com.listup.android D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=ca30d2f6-1415-4437-89ae-71acd0a0a7cd
 02-24 16:25:57.966 9918-14402/com.listup.android D/OkHttp: ������JFIF����������������C��: %# , #&')*)-0-(0%()
(����C   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((����0d"���
���������������������� 
02-24 16:25:57.966 9918-14402/com.listup.android D/OkHttp: ������������}��!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�
```

The problem is that I want to send `multiple images` to an array ant the number of images is not fixed. On server side they will be a part of user object's element like this:

```
 {
  "user":{
  "name":"Mukeka",
  "email":"abc@gmail.com",
  "images":[
     {
        "index":0,
        "url":"http://url.com/1.jpg"
     },
     {
        "index":1,
        "url":"http://url.com/2.jpg"
     }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Call<ApiResponse> sendFeedbackWithImage(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> descriptions,
                         @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> images);
```

use partmap to add params and list to add images